# How to avoid nested objects null validation in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I'm tired of null validations to prevent undefined errors, like:

```
function do(){
    if(!!object && !!object.childObject && !!object.childObject.prop)
        doSomethingWithProp(object.childObject.prop);
}
```

**Why?**

If the validation was only `if(!!object.childObject.prop)` I could get `undefined` error with `childObject` or `object`.

Comment: wow.... in suggested questions this topic didn't appear

Comment: You can also use underscore or lodash, i.e. _.has(myObject, "some.Nested.Propert.Path.In.MyObject") will return true/false, or you can use _.get(myObject, "some.Nested.Propert.Path.In.MyObject", fallbackValueHere) to get that nested property if it exists, and if it doesn't, then fallbackValueHere will be returned instead. That's essentially what the accepted answer from the link posted above is doing, but in a more performant and easier to use manner.

Comment: You don't need the `!!`.

Comment: It is for semantics. Without `!!` looks like `boolean`